# Get Image as stream or byte array using OpenRasta

Tags: rest, openrasta

Would anyone be able to give me a quick pointer as to how I can get an OpenRasta handler that returns a byte array. To be exposed in the ResourceSpace without it being a JSON or XML object. i.e. I don't want it transcoded, I just want to be able to set the media type to "image/PNG" or similar.

Using ASP.Net MVC I can do it using a FileContentResult by returning

```
File(myByteArray, "image/PNG");
```

I just need to know the OpenRasta equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just return a byte array as part of your handlerm but that will end up being served as application/octet-stream.

If you want to return files, you can simply return an implementation of IFile.

```
public class MyFileHandler {
  public IFile Get(int id) {
    var mybytes = new byte[];
    return new InMemoryFile(new MemoryStream(mybytes)) {
      ContentType = new MediaType("image/png");
    }
  }
}
```

You can also set the FileName property to return a specific filename, which will render a Content-Disposition header for you.

Answer (score 2):

I looked this up on the OpenRasta mailing list and there were a couple of related posts:
http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/5ae2a6d653a7421e#
http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/a631d3629b25b88a#

I have got it going with the following sample:

Configuration:

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<IFile>()
   .AtUri("/customer/{id}/avatar")
   .HandledBy<CustomerAvatarHandler>();
```

Handler:

```
public class CustomerAvatarHandler
{
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        const string filename = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Sunset.jpg";
        return new InMemoryFile(File.OpenRead(filename));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question re byte[] but I'm sure you can turn a byte array into a Stream via MemoryStream or something.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some Stream codecs out there, but you can do it as simply as this

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<byte[]>()
                .AtUri("/MyImageUri")
                .HandledBy<ImageHandler>();
```

where Image handler returns a byte array made from a System.Drawing.Graphics object in my case.

Any other answers that shed more light on this topic would be appreciated.